# pg_prewarm like funcationality in MySQL

Tags: mysql, cache, shared-buffers

I know in Postgres, we can **explicitly** load a table into the cache using pg_prewarm extension, is there a similar mechanism/UDF/etc in MySQL? I know MySQL would cache data in shared buffer **implicitly**, but is there a way to **explicitly** do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the same thing, but see `innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown` as a way of somewhat quickly getting back to where you left off after a shutdown.  It saves pointers to blocks, so shutdown is not slowed significantly.

A crude alternative is to do something like `SELECT AVG(col) FROM tbl` where `col` is not indexed.  However, if the table is bigger than the buffer_pool, be aware that some of the cached data will be pushed out before the query is finished.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I can confirm that all data is in shared buffer now, thanks!